# Parsec Haskell Lists

Tags: html, parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm using [`Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec.html) and [`Text.XHtml`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xhtml-3000.2.2.1/docs/Text-XHtml.html) to parse an input and get a HTML output.

If my input is:

```
    * First item, First level
    ** First item, Second level
    ** Second item, Second level
    * Second item, First level
```

My output should be:

`<ul><li>First item, First level <ul><li>First item, Second level </li><li>Second item, Second level </li></ul></li><li>Second item, First level</li></ul>`

I wrote this, but obviously does not work recursively

```haskell
list = do{ s <- many1 item;return (olist << s) }
item = do{ 
    (count 1 (char '*'))
    ;s <- manyTill anyChar newline
    ;return ( li <<  s)
  }
```

Any ideas?
The recursion can be more than two levels.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list n = do first <- item n
            rest <- many $ try $ try (list (n+1)) <|> item n
            return $ ulist << (first : rest)

item n = do count n (char '*')
            s <- manyTill anyChar newline
            return $ li << s
```

Now `parse  (list 1) "foo" "* a\n** a 1\n** a 2\n* b\n** b 1\n** b 2\n"` will return what you asked for.

Note though, that the nested lists should themselves be inside a li, for this to be valid xhtml.

Comment: Thanks! but when I do 
`parse (list 1) "foo" "* a\n** a 1\n** a 2\n* b\n** b 1\n** b 2\n"`

returns

  <ul> 
      <li> 
         a
      </li> 
      <li> 
         * a 1
      </li> 
      <li> 
         * a 2
      </li> 
      <li> 
          b
      </li> 
      <ul> 
         <li> 
             b 1
         </li> 
         <li> 
             b 2
         </li> 
      </ul> 
   </ul>

Comment: @Martin: Bah, you're right. I didn't read the output carefully enough when I tested.

Comment: Could you please help me to improve the output?
Thanks!!

Comment: @Martin: Fixed now. I had to add a second try in line two, so it wouldn't fail when reaching the end of a nested list.

Comment: Shouldn't you add a call to 'space' in item to eat the space between the asterisks and the text?